# Add x,y Values to numpy Matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix

So, what I have is a data file in the form of

```
1 , 1 , 2
2 , 5 , 8
3 , 9 , 10
...
...
```

In my case, every single triplet is in the form of: value , x-position , y-position.

What i want to achieve is to insert this data in a 2d-matrix, which I already created using the np.zeros function. However, I am stuck and can't figure out how to write a function which puts the given values to the right x and y position in the matrix :/

My current Matrix (named matrix) looks like:

```
array([[0,0,0,...,0]
       [0,0,0,...,0]
       [...        ]
       [0,0,0,...,0]])
```

and if i would use matrix[1,1]=2 (first line of data) i would get:

```
array([[0,0,0,...,0]
       [0,2,0,...,0]
       [...        ]
       [0,0,0,...,0]])
```

My goal is to insert all lines of data in this way.

Comment: I do not entirely get why the first row, third column is located at `1,1`? Can you speify how the values of the input, should map on the coordinates in the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**`np.genfromtxt`** function [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) where you set as `delimiter=…` parameter, the comma (`','`). So given you made a file `data.txt`, you can load that file into a numpy array with:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',')
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  8.],
       [ 3.,  9., 10.]])
```

Or if you are only interested in the *x*/*y* values, you can use the `usecols=…` parameter:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2))
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10.]])
```

Comment: Oh, i think i wasn't specific enough in my question, so i will update it .A matrix like this wasn't my goal. Thanks none the less!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data using `genfromtxt()`:

```
import numpy as np
tmp = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=int)
```

and then generate an empty data matrix `a` from the first two columns of `tmp`

```
a = np.zeros(np.max(tmp[:, :2], axis=0) + 1)
```

and populate it with values from `tmp`

```
a[tmp[:, 0], tmp[:, 1]] = tmp[:, 2]
a
# array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10.]])
```